# c++ List Elements Randomly Not Deleted By Loop

Tags: c++, list, dictionary

I have a function that randomly deletes elements from a map called bunnies (the map contains class objects) and a list called names ( the list contains the keys to the map) when the number of elements reach  more than 250.  However, randomly the map element will be deleted but the list entry will not (I think this is what is going on, though clearly part of the map element survives).  The outcome is that when I use the second section of code to iterate through the list and display the mapped values associated with those keys, I get large negative values like the example at the bottom.

Clearly the list element isn't being deleted, but why?

```
void cull(std::map<std::string, Bunny> &bunnies, std::list<std::string> &names,int n)
{
    int number = n, position = 0;
    for (number = n; number > 125; number--)
    {
        position = rand() % names.size();
        std::list<std::string>::iterator it = names.begin();
        std::advance(it, position);
        bunnies.erase(*it);
        names.erase(it);
        it = names.begin();
    }
    std::cout << "\n" << n - 125 << "rabbits culled";
}
```

I use this code to print out the map values.

```
for (std::list<std::string>::iterator it = names.begin(); it != names.end(); it++)
    {
        n++;
        std::cout << n << "\t" << " " << *it << "\t" << bunnies[*it].a() << "\t" << bunnies[*it].s() << "\t" << bunnies[*it].c() << "\t" << bunnies[*it].st() << "\n";
```

This is the output. The top is what it should display, the bottom is what happens when the program fails.

```
165      Tom_n  14      1       0       1
166      Lin_c  -842150451      -842150451      -842150451      -842150451
```

Comment: One question:  Why are you doing this? `bunnies[*it].~Bunny();`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry that's not suppose to be there and doesn't affect the problem (happens with it there and without it).

Comment: Never ever call the destructor directly! It should be called automatically. It's a wonder the application doesn't crash.

Comment: @jeffpkamp Why the magic number `125`?

Comment: `std::advance(it, number)` should be `std::advance(it, position)` instead.

Comment: The `position` variable doesn't seem to be read anywhere...

Comment: You're not even using the 'position' variable. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Just part of my silly rabbit population simulator to keep the population manageable.

Comment: @jeffpkamp - Code that erases from a container should never assume what the size is of the container(s) with magic numbers.  There are much safer and surer ways to write this code without going out of bounds, regardless of what values are passed to the function and without using magic numbers.

Comment: @agentNil I corrected that but not change to the problem.

Comment: @jeffpkamp What is the purpose of the condition, "number = n; number > 125; number--"? What does the param n represent?

Comment: @agentNil The deletions happen when the number of elements (Rabbits) exceed 250.  This program randomly erases(Kills) the elements until there are only 125 left.

Comment: @jeffpkamp - The design is flawed if a Bunny can have duplicate names in the list.  A `std::map` and a `std::list` cannot be used together unless you decide that a `std::list` must have unique names.

Comment: @jeffpkamp Have you tried running it though a debugger? It will help to see what's going on when the code executes.

Comment: You should trying looking out your data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be this:

```
 std::advance(it, number);
```

This should be `position`, not `number`.

The other problem is that a `map` stores unique names.  What if there is more than one Bunny with the same name?  For example, if the `list` has 3 bunnies names "John", the map will be able to hold only one "John", since the key in a map must be unique.

Either use a `multimap` if names can be duplicated, or use a `std::set` instead of a `std::list` if Bunnies must have unique names.

Maybe overall, you can just use `std::map<std::string, Bunny>`, and forget about the `std::list`.  The map by itself has all the information you need.  Unless there is something I'm missing, I don't see the need for a `std::list` to do redundant work.

Comment: I changed this and it was not the problem.  This just means it deletes a non-random element from the list since `number` is always shorter than the size of the list.  `Position` is just a random number that is less than the size of the list.

Comment: I updated my answer.  You need to decide if Bunnies have unique names or not.

Comment: the names are 16 "First names" with a randomly assigned ascii character for a last name, giving about 4000 possible names.  Since I keep my list below 250 members the chances of two identical members is pretty small.  That said I also have a separate part of the program not shown which makes sure newly generated names are not already in the list.

Comment: @jeffpkamp So why use a `std::list<std::string>`?  Use a `std::set<std::string>` and you don't have any of these issues, giving you 0% chance of a duplicate.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the cull method? Have you tried to print out all the bunnies right before calling it?

Comment: @Bedford Yes, I just doubled checked to make sure.  I have no problems before the cull function is called, messed up data after the cull function is called.

Comment: @jeffpkamp - Maybe you should post a small, but complete program that duplicates the problem.  You are claiming all of these things, but no one knows for sure.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie acutally I think what you said about the naming might be right... I'm seeing my name checker wasn't working.  I'm correcting it now to see if that was the problem.

Comment: @jeffpkamp - How about doing this before you erase from the map: `std::map<std::string, Bunny>::it2 = bunnies.find(*it); if (it2 == bunnies.end()) { ... bunny not found in map... }`

Comment: @jeffpkamp - If that is the issue, then I don't see the need for a `std::list<std::string>`.  Just use `std::map<std::string, Bunny>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  It was a problem with duplicate names!  My loop to catch duplicate names got messed up when I was editing something else.  I'm learning C++ in my free time, so I am probably doing somethings that are a bit silly.  I see what you mean about just using the map.